# Certbot (LetsEncrypt) on custom port (Nginx OR apache)

Tags: nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

I've found many similar questions, people asking about **how-to** setup SSL on different ports (other than 80/443), i.e. `1234` port.
However, all answers were like `use redirection` or `proxying requests` or `dns-validation (instead of http)` or [use alternative approaches](https://serverfault.com/questions/805666/certbot-letsencrypt-on-different-port-than-443). However, nowhere you can find even a single answer  *in StackExchange manner*, I mean step-by-step for newbie, how to do that.

However, note, redirection is not solution, because on 80/443 a person might have a regular website, but on 1234 port a completely different app. So, just "redirection" from `1234` to `80` will mess-up sites, right?

Comment: This one https://serverfault.com/questions/805666/certbot-letsencrypt-on-different-port-than-443 is manual (hand-made) solution, which is not convenient.

Answer (score 5):

It's perfectly fine to have Nginx on port 80 merely for [HTTP-01 challenge](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#http-01-challenge) and then use the certificates created using it on another web applications or even another server software altogether. It doesn't need to perform any reverse proxying in order to serve the `http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/`, e.g.

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name example.com;

   location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
       alias /var/www/letsencrypt/.well-known/acme-challenge/;
   }
   location / {
       return 404;
   }
}
```

Furthermore, you don't necessarily need a web server listening on port 80 at all, as Certbot can use its own built-in web server for handling the challenges:

```
sudo certbot certonly --standalone --preferred-challenges http -d example.com
```

Comment: The port `1234` is used in whichever application is used to serve the website.

Comment: You only need port 80 at the time the certificate is issued, usually once every 2 months per certificate. After that you can use the certificate everywhere you want. Think of using the certificate for an email server (SMTP&IMAP) which can't even answer HTTP challenge, as it's not talking the HTTP protocol. Also, even with the port 80 you won't use it FOR that port, but for TLS on another port 443.

Comment: Can you tell also for Apache? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To extend @Esa's nice answer, here is what exact steps I did for Apache:

1. Generate the certificate as @Esa said.
2. Go to `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` and change `80` or `443` to whatever port you want
3. Also in `/sites-available/example.com` change the VirtualHost to desired port. Ensure, there are the commands for SSL file paths (resulted from the certbot installation)
4. `systemctl restart apache2`

---

p.s. People who needs for **WordPress**, ensure that redirection doesn't redirect to old port. Before changing that in WP Dashboard>Settings, you can set this in `wp-config':

```
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com:1234/');
define('WP_HOME','https://example.com:1234/');
```